# How to change language of more link text in fullcalendar 5

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using `fullcalendar 5` with Spanish locale. All texts appear in Spanish but when a `n more` link appears. That text still appears in English.

I was searching in the docs but I did not find how to change the language of that text.

And the big problem with the Demo page that I hope it should be fixed is that it shows what can the plugin do, but it does not show how to do it.

For example, in this page: https://fullcalendar.io/demos when selecting Locales menu option I can see that text was translated to Russian, but when click on `more info`, no info about that is found.

Any hint?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/vYRXyEb is a copy of the code from the more complete fullCalendar locales demo (found at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/localization). It shows that if you switch to Spanish, the "more" link is definitely translated to Spanish. It's unclear why you're having a problem. Are you able to provide a [mre] of the issue for investigation?

Comment: P.S. All the demos found in the home page / demos page are reproduced elsewhere in the documentation, with CodePen links to back them up, showing the source code.